# Rounding Up Minute at 30 Seconds and Flooring

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have a time value that looks like so: `totalDuration: 00:22:53`. What I want to do is round up the seconds on this value when the `seconds >= 30` so that it's rounded up to the next minute and zeroed on the seconds.

In other words, my example of `00:22:53` should end up being `00:23:00`.

To do that I tried this:

```
const timeRoundedUp = moment(totalDuration).add(1, 'm').startOf('minute');
```

But this gives me a `null` result.

I also tried this:

```
const roundedUp = moment(totalDuration).add(1, 'minutes');
```

But that also gives me a `null` result.

Maybe the issue is the format of the value I am inputting into the function? How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must specify the format of your duration for the moment initialize the right object

```
let totalDuration = '00:22:53'
const m = moment(totalDuration, "hh:mm:ss");

// conditionally round the seconds
const roundUp = m.second() >= 30 ? m.add(1, 'minute').startOf('minute') : m.startOf('minute')

console.log(roundUp.format("HH:mm:ss"));
```